# Statistics task

Tags: statistics

I have very simple math task to solve but as am not a math person, I would kindly ask for your help.
The task: 30% of students failed test.the test average score was 7.5 and standart deviation was 1.3. What was the needed score to pass the test?
That's all info I have. Hope it makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume a normal distribution of test scores. Approximately 68% of the marks will lie inside 1 standard deviation. So the approximately 16% of the students will have marks less than 7.5-1.3=6.2

Since 50% of the students have marks less than 7.5, it's reasonable to set a passing score of 7.5-(1.3/2)=6.85

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer and help. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @thebumbkid - I have accepted it, sorry didn't press it before. One more quick question how do you get to the 68% and 16% mathematically, what calculations does give you that numbers? Thank you

Comment: This value is a rough estimate, for a theoretical value, you need to evaluate the integral of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) $N(7.5, 1.5^2)$ from $-\infty$ to $\alpha$ and set that value equal to $30\%$. The value of $ \alpha$ would give you a precise answer for the passing score.